# Load capacitance of transceiver

Tags: oscillator

I am using [88E1512-A0-NNP2I000](https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/transceivers/marvell-phys-transceivers-alaska-88e151x-datasheet.pdf) in my design. It requires 25MHz clock signal on its XTAL_IN pin.

I will be providing the required 25MHz clock using [ASTMLPE-18-25.000MHZ-ER-ET](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/3/ASTMLP-1847855.pdf).

In the datasheet of [88E1512-A0-NNP2I000](https://www.marvell.com/content/dam/marvell/en/public-collateral/transceivers/marvell-phys-transceivers-alaska-88e151x-datasheet.pdf), it is mentioned that "XTAL_IN Rise" and "XTAL_IN Fall" should be 3ns(typical value).
[image]

[ASTMLPE-18-25.000MHZ-ER-ET](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/3/ASTMLP-1847855.pdf) has different Rise and fall-time based up on the CLoad.

[image]

I have following questions.

1. Is this Cload means the capacitance load offered by the "XTAL_In" pin of    transceiver?
2. In the datasheet of transceiver(page number 134) it is mentioned that "Input capacitance" of all pins is "5pF". This value will be CLoad for [ASTMLPE-18-25.000MHZ-ER-ET](https://www.mouser.in/datasheet/2/3/ASTMLP-1847855.pdf)?

[image]

Comment: Neither are crystals; they are both MEMS oscillators and both are not recommended for new designs.

Comment: @Andyaka I am using them for existing design. I have purchased ASTMLPE-18-25.000MHZ-ER-ET in bulk quantity!

Answer (score 4):

1. The Cload is all capacitive load on the oscillator output. So, not only the input pin capacitance Cin of the Ethernet chip, but also any additional capacitance of PCB traces and component pads. You need to estimate or measure the additional capacitances to know what the actual load on the oscillator is.
2. The datasheet could be more clear on this, as it says all pins have 5pF input capacitance, but then it reads all digital inputs, and crystal oscillator pins on chips are not purely digital pins. It is a good assumption unless datasheets or application notes don't indicate otherwise. Like I said in the previous point, there are other capacitances loading the oscillator output as well, not just the chip input capacitance.

One difference is that the chip datasheet says rise and fall time is 3ns measured from 10% to 90%, while the crystal oscillator says rise and fall times are measured between 20% and 80%, which means it actually takes longer to achieve 10% to 90%.

On the other hand, the chip says only typical value of 3ns, there is no hard limit for acceptable values. So, whether or not this is a suitable component to your existing design, it depends on your design.

Comment: I need to just calculate the capacitance of traces and soldering pads connecting oscillator output to ethernet chip input pins?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is covered in the document [SiTime Oscillator Rise and Fall Time Selection for SiT8103, SiT8003, and SiT9003](https://www.mouser.com/pdfDocs/sitime-an10022-rise-and-fall-time.pdf). If you further narrow the search when browsing mouser.com, you may find the document more specific for your ASTMLP device.

In the document of my reference, see

item 3 in section **Driving Large Loads Up To 60 pF**:

> ... If rise/fall times other than the ones provided by standard devices are required, look at the boxes that provide the acceptable rise/fall times desired for the application. Refer to Tables 5 through 8 to find out the maximum frequency supported for the corresponding box in Tables 1 through 4. ...

and section **Reducing Rise/Fall Time for EMI Reduction**:

> In some applications, EMI may be reduced by choosing slower clock rise and fall times. The slower rise/fall edges reduce the higher clock harmonics in a digital clock signal, minimizing EMI radiation at these harmonics. ...

Comment: I couldn't find any document from Abracon. I have edited the question.